# Получить данные из вложенного объекта Json

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

Имеется такой Json файл

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 47.5,
        "lat": 42.98
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 802,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "scattered clouds",
            "icon": "03n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 15.28,
        "feels_like": 14.85,
        "temp_min": 15,
        "temp_max": 15.56,
        "pressure": 1014,
        "humidity": 87
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 2,
        "deg": 140
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 37
    },
    "dt": 1589559748,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 8965,
        "country": "RU",
        "sunrise": 1589506004,
        "sunset": 1589558769
    },
    "timezone": 10800,
    "id": 532096,
    "name": "Makhachkala",
    "cod": 200
}
```

Мне оттуда нужны `description`, который находится внутри `weather`, `temp`, который находится внутри `main`, `humidity`, который находится внутри `temp`, и `name` в конце списка

POJO класс (если закомментировать все поля и методы кроме `location` и `getLocation`, то я получаю местоположение. В противном случае ничего не получаю)

```
public class WeatherLocation {
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String location;

    @SerializedName("main")
    @Expose
    private WeatherTemp weatherTemp;

    @SerializedName("weather")
    @Expose
    private WeatherDescription weatherDescription;

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public WeatherTemp getWeatherTemp() {
        return weatherTemp;
    }

    public WeatherDescription getWeatherDescription() {
        return weatherDescription;
    }
}
```

POJO класс 2

```
public class WeatherTemp {
    @SerializedName("temp")
    @Expose
    private int temp;

    @SerializedName("humidity")
    @Expose
    private int humidity;

    public int getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public int getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }
}
```

POJO класс 3

```
public class WeatherTemp {
    @SerializedName("temp")
    @Expose
    private int temp;

    @SerializedName("humidity")
    @Expose
    private int humidity;

    public int getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public int getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
NetworkRequest.getRequest()
                .getWeatherApi()
                .getWeather()
                .enqueue(new Callback<WeatherLocation>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<WeatherLocation> call, Response<WeatherLocation> response) {
                        WeatherLocation weatherLocation = response.body();
                        tvLocation.setText(weatherLocation.getLocation());
                        tvTemperature.setText(weatherLocation.getWeatherTemp().getTemp());
                        tvDescription.setText(weatherLocation.getWeatherDescription().getDescription());
                        tvHumidity.setText(weatherLocation.getWeatherTemp().getHumidity());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<WeatherLocation> call, Throwable t) {
                    }
                });

    }
```

В итоге я получаю данные только от `getLocale`. При получении остальных выбрасывается исключение

Comment: а вы классы приложить можете в которых находятся эти поля?

Comment: @Andrew приложил

Comment: я использовал другие наименования класса, но суть я думаю будет ясна)) остальные данные можно получать аналогичным путем :)

Comment: обновил немного ответ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы предложил сделать класс который будет отвечать за поля которые вам нужны. Вероятнее всего они есть, но вы получаете не массив а только один объект. То есть например, вместо массива `"weather"` вы получаете только один объект который противоречит тому что приходит. Поэтому делаем класс для json weather:

```
"weather": [
        {
            "id": 802,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "scattered clouds",
            "icon": "03n"
        }
    ],
```

---

```
public class Weather {

private Integer id;
private String main;
private String description;
private String icon;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public Weather withId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
return this;
}

public String getMain() {
return main;
}

public void setMain(String main) {
this.main = main;
}

public Weather withMain(String main) {
this.main = main;
return this;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public Weather withDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
return this;
}

public String getIcon() {
return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
this.icon = icon;
}

public Weather withIcon(String icon) {
this.icon = icon;
return this;
}

}
```

и дальше есть вместо этого варианта:

```
@SerializedName("weather")
@Expose
private WeatherDescription weatherDescription;
```

делаем так:

```
private ArrayList<Weather> weatherDescription;
```

то есть вы будете ждать массив объектов класса Weather. Для генерации класса использовал [этот](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) инструмент. И дальше после получения ответа вы можете получить массив. Так же советую добавить условие `isSuccessful` для response:

```
if(response.isSuccessful){
//обрабатываем  то что пришло
}
```

таким образом вы сможете предотвратить ошибку если сервер вернет не 200 ответ. И собственно дальше получаем массив weather:

```
if(response.isSuccessful){
    WeatherLocation weatherLocation = response.body();
    ArrayList<Weather> weatherDescr = weatherLocation.getWeatherDescription()
    for(i in 0 until weatherDescr.size){
     // получаем элементы массива описания погоды
      Weather weather = weatherDescr[i]
      weather.description // получили описание

    }
}
```

получение "main" будет происходить немного по другому сценарию. Вы получаете jsonObject. А значит его нужно будет конвертировать в класс. Я бы вам советовал в главном классе ответа `WeatherLocation` вместо поля:

```
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private WeatherTemp weatherTemp;
```

использовать другой тип данных:

```
private JsonObject main;
```

таким образом вы сможете получить json который пришел с сервера. Следующим этапом будет его конвертация в объект класса который вы создали. Для начала получим его из response:

```
weatherLocation.getMain()
```

и дальше конвертация будет происходить [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308452/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-java-object):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
WeatherTemp tempClass= gson.fromJson(json, WeatherTemp.class);
```

ну и дальше уже можно будет получать переменные из объекта класса.